# Best way to handle gateway timeout (error 504) on file upload

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, timeout

There is a route I use for handling CSV upload, the route will accept a CSV file and writing data to DB.
The problem is, if the request is taking too long (maybe more than 3 minutes when the file has lots of data) the server will return error 504 (Gateway timeout), but the request keeps going.
Is there a better way to handle this situation. Maybe a way to do the writing process in the background?

I'm using ExpressJS and multer for the file upload, MySQL and Mongo for the DB.